# Why is my frontend React app working in localhost but not in Vercel (or any other platform)

Tags: reactjs, deployment, frontend, vercel

I have a problem. My [frontend](https://github.com/aztecbinaynay/proflanner-fe-final/tree/main) works in my localhost (you can open a codespace in this repo/branch and it works.) but deploying it in Vercel ([link](https://proflanner-fe-final-ez9r32ntc-aztecbinaynay.vercel.app/)) doesn't work as it just gives me a white screen!

Vercel isn't giving me any errors and I am finding this hard to debug. I have already deployed my backend and database server and just need for this frontend to work.

[image: picture of my vercel deployed frontend that shows white screen.]
picture of my vercel deployed frontend that shows white screen.

[image: picture of my frontend running on my localhost]
picture of my frontend running on my localhost

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna look like a fool here but it is what it is lol. The reason why it did not work was because in my package.json, I had typed

`"homepage": <gitub pages URL>`

I replaced it with:

```
"homepage":"."
```